# Steam Store API question about getting response meant for USA instead of Canada

Tags: node.js, api, discord, discord.js, steam

I am hosting a Discord Bot on a server in Canada.  When I do

```js
let response = await fetch("http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=251570")
```

I get a response with the `price_overview` information in CAD. I would like it in USD because I am located in the US.  Is there anyway to get the USD response instead of the CAD response? (preferably without just doing the math to convert CAD to USD)

Comment: Just divide by 1.25 and you get the approximate CAD to USD

Answer (score 3):

You can append `&cc=us&l=en` to the URL to get the price in USD:

https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=251570&cc=us&l=en

which yields:

```json
price_overview: {
    currency: "USD",
    initial: 2499,
    final: 2499,
    discount_percent: 0,
    initial_formatted: "",
    final_formatted: "$24.99"
},
```

So in your code:

```js
let response = await fetch("https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=251570&cc=us&l=en")
```

Note: This is an unofficial API and could change anytime.